# grails.plugin.location don't work with 1.4M1?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

BuildConfig.groovy

> grails.plugin.location.'tzlib' = "../tzlib"

got warning:

> Welcome to Grails 1.4.0.M1 -
>   http://grails.org/ Licensed under
>   Apache Standard License 2.0 Grails
>   home is set to: D:\Tool\Grails\
>
> Base Directory: D:\Workspace\TZ\AMP
>   Running script Compile.groovy
>   Environment set to development Setting
>   non-interactive mode Checking 2
>   changing plugins for remote updates,
>   please wait ... :: problems summary ::
>
> :::: WARNINGS
>   module not found: org.grails.plugins#tzlib;0.1
>
> ==== grailsPlugins: tried
>
> ```
> -- artifact
> ```
>
> org.grails.plugins#tzlib;0.1!tzlib.zip:
>
> D:\Workspace\TZ\AMP/lib/tzlib-0.1.zip
>
> D:\TZProfile.grails\1.4.0.M1\projects\AMP\plugins\build-test-data-1.1.1/lib/tzlib-0.1.zip
>
> D:\TZProfile.grails\1.4.0.M1\projects\AMP\plugins\console-1.0.1/lib/tzlib-0.1.zip
>
> D:\TZProfile.grails\1.4.0.M1\projects\AMP\plugins\fixtures-1.0.7/lib/tzlib-0.1.zip
>
> D:\TZProfile.grails\1.4.0.M1\projects\AMP\plugins\hibernate-1.4.0.M1/lib/tzlib-0.1.zip
>
> D:\TZProfile.grails\1.4.0.M1\projects\AMP\plugins\jquery-1.6.1.1/lib/tzlib-0.1.zip
>
> D:\TZProfile.grails\1.4.0.M1\projects\AMP\plugins\quartz-1.0-SNAPSHOT/lib/tzlib-0.1.zip
>
> D:\TZProfile.grails\1.4.0.M1\projects\AMP\plugins\resources-1.0/lib/tzlib-0.1.zip
>
> D:\TZProfile.grails\1.4.0.M1\projects\AMP\plugins\shiro-1.1.3/lib/tzlib-0.1.zip
>
> D:\TZProfile.grails\1.4.0.M1\projects\AMP\plugins\spock-0.6-SNAPSHOT/lib/tzlib-0.1.zip
>
> D:\TZProfile.grails\1.4.0.M1\projects\AMP\plugins\tomcat-1.4.0.M1/lib/tzlib-0.1.zip
>
> ==== grailsHome: tried
>
> D:\Tool\Grails/lib/org.grails.plugins/tzlib/ivy-0.1.xml
>
> ```
> -- artifact
> ```
>
> org.grails.plugins#tzlib;0.1!tzlib.zip:
>
> D:\Tool\Grails/lib/org.grails.plugins/tzlib/jars/tzlib-0.1.zip
>
> D:\Tool\Grails/lib/org.grails.plugins/tzlib/bundles/tzlib-0.1.zip
>
> ==== grailsHome: tried
>
> D:\Tool\Grails\src\libs/tzlib-0.1.xml
>
> ```
> -- artifact
> ```
>
> org.grails.plugins#tzlib;0.1!tzlib.zip:
>
> D:\Tool\Grails\src\libs/tzlib-0.1.zip
>
> ==== grailsHome: tried
>
> ```
> D:\Tool\Grails\dist/tzlib-0.1.xml
>
> -- artifact
> ```
>
> org.grails.plugins#tzlib;0.1!tzlib.zip:
>
> ```
> D:\Tool\Grails\dist/tzlib-0.1.zip
> ```
>
> ==== grailsHome: tried
>
> ```
> -- artifact
> ```
>
> org.grails.plugins#tzlib;0.1!tzlib.zip:
>
> D:\Tool\Grails/plugins/grails-tzlib-0.1.zip
>
> ====
>   http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins:
>   tried
>
> http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/grails/plugins/tzlib/0.1/tzlib-0.1.pom
>
> ```
> -- artifact
> ```
>
> org.grails.plugins#tzlib;0.1!tzlib.zip:
>
> http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/grails/plugins/tzlib/0.1/tzlib-0.1.zip
>
> ==== grailsCentral: tried
>
> http://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins/grails-ivy/tags/RELEASE_0_1/ivy-0.1.pom
>
> ```
> -- artifact
> ```
>
> org.grails.plugins#tzlib;0.1!tzlib.zip:
>
> http://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins/grails-tzlib/tags/RELEASE_0_1/grails-tzlib-0.1.zip
>
> ==== grailsCore: tried
>
> http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/grails-ivy/tags/RELEASE_0_1/ivy-0.1.pom
>
> ```
> -- artifact
> ```
>
> org.grails.plugins#tzlib;0.1!tzlib.zip:
>
> http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/grails-tzlib/tags/RELEASE_0_1/grails-tzlib-0.1.zip
>
> ==== mavenCentral: tried
>
> http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/tzlib/0.1/tzlib-0.1.pom
>
> ```
> -- artifact
> ```
>
> org.grails.plugins#tzlib;0.1!tzlib.zip:
>
> http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/tzlib/0.1/tzlib-0.1.zip
>
> ====
>   http://download.java.net/maven/2/:
>   tried
>
> http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/grails/plugins/tzlib/0.1/tzlib-0.1.pom
>
> ```
> -- artifact
> ```
>
> org.grails.plugins#tzlib;0.1!tzlib.zip:
>
> http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/grails/plugins/tzlib/0.1/tzlib-0.1.zip
>
> ====
>   http://m2repo.spockframework.org/snapshots:
>   tried
>
> http://m2repo.spockframework.org/snapshots/org/grails/plugins/tzlib/0.1/tzlib-0.1.pom
>
> ```
> -- artifact
> ```
>
> org.grails.plugins#tzlib;0.1!tzlib.zip:
>
> http://m2repo.spockframework.org/snapshots/org/grails/plugins/tzlib/0.1/tzlib-0.1.zip
>
> ```
>   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
>
>   ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES
> ```
>
> ::
>
> ```
>   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
>
>   :: org.grails.plugins#tzlib;0.1: not
> ```
>
> found
>
> ```
>   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
> ```
>
> Failed to resolve plugins.

Comment: my project is \Workspace\TZ' and plugin: '\Workspace\tzlib'